# Adding mapping on elasticsearch using curl

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I am trying to add elasticsearch mapping but I am facing an exception

> {"error":"InvalidTypeNameException[mapping type name [*mapping] can't
>   start with '*']","status":400}

I am using 0.99.10 version of elasticSearchIndex.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/_mapping/tweet' -d '{"tweet" : {"properties" : {"message" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true }}}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you include the document type in the url you should start your payload by *properties* field, like this:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/_mapping/tweet' -d '{"properties" : {"message" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true }}}'
```

As described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html)